# wxPython Multiple Splitter Windows

Tags: wxpython, panels, splitter

I'm trying to embed splitter windows in set of panels, but when I run the following I see a flash, as if the top splitter window is overlaying the top panel of the second splitter window. I tried to keep track of the children of the frame and panels but can't figure  out whos on top. Can anyone help me sort this out and explain why the layout changes and the top panel is  apparantly masked by the 2nd panel added to the splitter?
Thanks
David

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6
# encoding: ISO-8859-1
"""
Basic Splitter Panel Skeleton.py
"""

import sys
reload(sys) 
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
import os
import time
import wx


def timenow():
    return time.time()

########################################################################

class VSplitterPanel(wx.Panel):
    """ Constructs a Vertical splitter window with left and right panels"""
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, color):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(color)
        splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self, style = wx.SP_3D| wx.SP_LIVE_UPDATE)
        leftPanel = wx.Panel(splitter)
        rightPanel = wx.Panel(splitter)
        leftPanel.SetBackgroundColour('SEA GREEN')
        rightPanel.SetBackgroundColour('STEEL BLUE')

        splitter.SplitVertically(leftPanel, rightPanel) 
        PanelSizer=wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        PanelSizer.Add(splitter, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
        self.SetSizer(PanelSizer)
########################################################################

class HSplitterPanel(wx.Panel):
    """ Constructs a Horizontal splitter window with top and bottom panels"""
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, color):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(color)
        splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self, style = wx.SP_3D| wx.SP_LIVE_UPDATE)
        TopPanel = wx.Panel(splitter)
        BottomPanel = wx.Panel(splitter)
        TopPanel.SetBackgroundColour('YELLOW GREEN')
        BottomPanel.SetBackgroundColour('SLATE BLUE')


        splitter.SplitHorizontally(TopPanel, BottomPanel) 
        PanelSizer=wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        PanelSizer.Add(splitter, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
        self.SetSizer(PanelSizer)
########################################################################

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """Constructor"""
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Basic Splitter Panel Skeleton",size=(800,600))
        t0=timenow()
        self.sb=self.CreateStatusBar()
        ################################################################
        # Define mainsplitter as child of Frame and add H and VSplitterPanel as children
        mainsplitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self, style = wx.SP_3D| wx.SP_LIVE_UPDATE)
        #splitterpanel1 = HSplitterPanel(mainsplitter,'LIGHT BLUE') 
        splitterpanel1 = HSplitterPanel(mainsplitter,'LIGHT BLUE') 
        splitterpanel2 = VSplitterPanel(mainsplitter,'LIGHT BLUE') 
        #print self.GetChildren(),'\n'
        #print splitterpanel1.leftPanel.GetChildren()
        mainsplitter.SplitHorizontally(splitterpanel2, splitterpanel1)
        MainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        MainSizer.Add(mainsplitter, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
        self.SetSizer(MainSizer)
        #################################################################
        self.sb.SetStatusText('Initialized in  %6.4f secs'%(timenow()-t0))
        self.Refresh()
        self.Show()

#---------------------------------------------------------------------- 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    MainFrame(None, -1)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the following when I run it on Windows:

[image]

Which panel is messed up? Regardless, the easiest way to tell which widget is where is to use the Widget Inspection Tool. You can read about it [here](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Widget%20Inspection%20Tool). It's easy to use and it can even make your sizers visible to help you figure out layout issues.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I expected the yellow green and slate blue panels in the bottom to be equally proportioned. Not to have the left and right panels overlay the yellow green panel. It looks like my mainsplitter isn't properly adding the HSplitter and VSplitter instance. I'll take a look at the widget inspector to see if that helps. Did you see the problem of the green flash when the program is launched?

Comment: Well I looked at the widget inspector and everything seems to be correctly placed. I suspect the problem is in one of the boxsizers resizing the splitterwindow when the frame is being drawn.

Comment: sizer.SetSashGravity(0.5) fixed the proportional display problem but there is still the layout screen display problem when the program fist starts.

Comment: I didn't see the flash. You could try using wx.CallAfter and pass it the self.Layout command. I've found that helpful before.

Comment: Thanks again Mike for the tip on wx.CallAfter and all your help. Turns out the flash was an artifact from my IDE. After restarting the IDE the flash is gone.